# user inputs information in form, then form information is displayed in same page

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to make a form which my friend can enter information and it will display on the same page so he inputs the title in a text field clicks submit and it will go in the title box , also he can put information into fields for example height and width and it will create a div with that height and width. this is what i got so far http://www.nathanrobjohn.com/ suggestions for best language to use etc would help alot thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  [jquery form plug in](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Comment: what and that will grab the width and height they enter and create a div with them ?